# mariadb 5.5.36 with innodb plugin

Tags: mysql, innodb, mariadb, xtradb, plugins

I installed mariadb 5.5.36 on a win32 system. Everything runs fine except innodb requests are 2 x slower than an identical MySQL installation. So I want to switch back to original innodb plugin to test the performance with it.

In my.ini I put under [mysqld] the following:

```
ignore_builtin_innodb
plugin-load=innodb=ha_innodb.dll
```

The plugin is located in BASEDIR/lib/plugin.

But when I start the service I get the following in the error log:

```
140315 18:03:04 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
140315 18:03:04 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
140315 18:03:04 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
140315 18:03:04 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
140315 18:03:04 [ERROR] Aborting
```

If I comment both lines out then everything runs fine.

Even when I try to run a plain MariaDB data dir (without the log files ...) the error occurs.

Is there someone who have a hint for me?

Answer (score 1):

The method of using 'innodb_plugin' instead of default InnoDB is a MySQL 5.1 feature. The InnoDB plugin of 5.1 is the default of MySQL 5.5, and thus, in MySQL 5.5 we see this information for the '[ignore_builtin_innodb](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#option_mysqld_ignore-builtin-innodb)':

> In MySQL 5.1, this option caused the server to behave as if the built-in InnoDB were not present, which enabled InnoDB Plugin to be used instead. In MySQL 5.5, InnoDB is the default storage engine and InnoDB Plugin is not used, so this option has no effect. As of MySQL 5.5.22, it is deprecated and its use results in a warning.

This would be true for MariaDB 5.5 as well.

Comment: But what do i have to do in order to activate the innodb plugin ha_innodb.dll ?